# Failed establishing a connection with websocket in an iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, websocket

I have integrated websocket into my iOS app via cocoapods. Tried establishing a connection, it throws an error. I have tried looking for solutions & implemented them, but they didn't work for me.

Here is how my piece of code looks like:

```
 { 
    webSocket.delegate = nil; 
    webSocket = nil;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ws://"]; 
   SRWebSocket *newWebSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    newWebSocket.delegate = self;
    [newWebSocket open];
```

I get the following error:

> error:Error Domain=SRWebSocketErrorDomain Code=2133 "Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response}.
>   Please help me out in fixing this.

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Here is how my piece of code looks like: 
{
 webSocket.delegate = nil;
 webSocket = nil;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ws://"];
//SRWebSocket *newWebSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
newWebSocket.delegate = self;
 [newWebSocket open];